# Dropdown PHP with SQL with two different queries in one line inside dropdown > (Name, Number)

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I want the dropdown to show the "client_code", "name" in one line. It almost works but not 100%. I am a beginner with php and SQL, can someone help me please?

**Code that doesn't work**

```
<form id="thirdForm" name="form1" action="" method="post">
<select id="klantWidth">
<?php
$queryKlant = "SELECT naam FROM klant";
$queryKlantCode = "SELECT klant_code FROM klant";
$resultKlant=mysqli_query($mysqli,$queryKlant);
$resultKlantCode=mysqli_query($mysqli,$queryKlantCode);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultKlant) && 
$row2=mysqli_fetch_array($resultKlantCode)  )
{
?>

<option><?php echo $row[0]. ", ". $row2[0];?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
</form>
```

**Code that only works with retrieving name in dropdown from database**

```
<form id="thirdForm" name="form1" action="" method="post">
<select id="klantWidth">
<?php
$queryKlant = "SELECT naam FROM klant";
$res=mysqli_query($mysqli,$queryKlant);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
?>
<option><?php echo $row[0]; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: `JOIN` the two queries and I also suggest using a `foreach` loop since it is easier to read and work with.

Comment: Can one of you please please please make it in a answer with code for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select more than one column from a table in the same select, and as both these columns live in the same table it makes producing this result much simpler.

```
<form id="thirdForm" name="form1" action="" method="post">
    <select id="klantWidth">

<?php
    $sql = "SELECT naam, klant_code FROM klant";

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>

        <option><?php echo $row[0]. ", ". $row[1];?></option>
<?php
    }
?>  
    </select>
</form>
```

You probably want to do this with your `<option>` tag as well rather than put the name and code in the visible portion

```
    <option value="<?php echo $row[1];?>"><?php echo $row[0];?> </option>
```

And if you use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` you can use the columns names so you know what you are putting where

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result){

    <option value="<?php echo $row['klant_code'];?>"><?php echo $row['naam'];?> </option>
```

Comment: Let my try something, i will get back to you

Comment: I am getting "syntax error, unexpected '?>" on the line under the while loop? Trying to fix that now but nothing works

Comment: For other people, the while loop was not closed

Comment: Yes, sorry fixed the missin `)` in the while loop now :) Silly me

Comment: Thank you so much, have a nice day!